# how to export wordpress pages,posts with media for another site

Tags: wordpress

I have wordpress site i need to export posts , pages with media and attachments engaged with them.
and need to use it in another wordpress site.

Also i have installed the woocommerce in it , i need to export the store settings, products, categories , tags with images used for it...

There are many custom post types used in my site. i need to also export theme with medias used...

I tried using Tools -> Import / Export but that does not exports the data with media or images.

Need an immediate help..

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I just found out how to do this today, and answered this question with a great guide with photos on how to use the export and import tools in WordPress to transfer photos to a new site to be used in posts and pages. This is done by editing the xml files to show the correctly transferred image URLs.

Since I can't post photos because of my reputation, here is the link.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/117344/failed-to-import-media/372304#372304

Answer (score 0):

> I have wordpress site i need to export posts , pages with media and attachments engaged with them. and need to use it in another wordpress site.
>
> Also i have installed the woocommerce in it , i need to export the store settings, products, categories , tags with images used for it...
>
> There are many custom post types used in my site. i need to also export theme with medias used...

I don't think so you had left something un-neccessary, So Download the database and import it wherever your new database you want to store.

Then download the `wp-content/themes`, `wp-content/uploads`, `wp-content/plugins` Directories. OR Simply Download your `wp-content` directory. Now you have everything.

### I have Everything Now?

Now download the wordpress from wordpress.org and install it to your server. After complete the Installation, Replace the `wp-content` directory with your new installed wordpress. We assigned our old stuff to New Wordpress.

Now its time to replace Database. There are several online tutorials to replace your old database to new one.

Comment: problem is i need to keep posts and pages of another site as it is. i can not export my database and import it in another site...else it will remove all posts and pages and other datas from that site..

Comment: @HasmukhMistry __"i need to export posts , pages with media and attachments"__ Means you want to extend your another site posts and pages with old one?

Comment: yes exactly... i need to take posts , pages from one site to another... same way i need to take woocommerce products and other stuff..

Comment: You have to make custom script that extend your new database with old one. But before that you have to know that __what is stored where__ ( Point is media ids,posts_ids - These that you have to extends with there data ) in wordpress database.

Comment: @HasmukhMistry No, i don't know. But Will develope it soon, Its cool ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can do this:

- Manual
- Using plugin

For manual, it's a little more lengthy process, you need to download complete files from one server and upload it to another. Do some changes to the backup DB i.e replacing urls and then uploading the DB file as well.

Other way, which is far more better is to use the plugin called as "All in one Migration". Here is the link which can guide you on the complete process:

https://makersbyte.com/easily-export-import-wordpress-sites/

Answer (score -1):

Exporting your WordPress site can be used for site moves or simple backups. In this guide, I’ll provide some simple and easy options to export your WordPress sites for both non-technical and technical people.

Exporting your site creates a backup of your site, usually in the form of a .tar.gz or .zip file, which you can then use to restore or migrate your site to another domain or host. Once you have the backup it’s an easy matter loading a blank WordPress site, loading the plugin, and then restoring the site from your backup file.
When you export your WordPress sites you have the choice to export all your posts, pages, comments, custom fields, terms, navigation menus, and custom posts but the downside to this approach and it’s that WordPress doesn’t export plugins, theme, and settings of your site.

**Export Site**

```
 1. Log into WordPress
 2. Go to Tools > Export
 3. Choose what you want to export:
    -All
    -Posts
    -Pages
    -Media 
 4. Click Download Export File. This will download a .xml file to your computer.
```

**Import Site**

```
 1. Log in to the WordPress site you want to import it to.
 2. Go to Tools > Import.
 3. Find the option called WordPress at the bottom and click Install
        Now.
 4. When it’s finished installing, click Run Importer.
 5. Upload the .xml file you exported.
```

Once you’ve completed exporting your site, you will want to test everything on the site. Make sure that you look for dead links, check menus, and any functionality or post that you consider important to your website.

It doesn’t have to be hard to export your WordPress sites. There are options for everyone, no matter what level of technical skill you have. And should you ever encounter a conflict, hack, or choose to move your site, having an export of your site is invaluable.